# Rails - Need help displaying database records associated with has_many :through in "show" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, has-many-through

I have quite a simple problem, but cant figure out how to solve it. I have two models: `Shop` and `Mall`, which are associated through a join table called `MallShops`. When a new shop is created, I have the option to link the shop to whatever malls currently existing in the database through check boxes. The issue is after I have saved the shops, I dont know how to display the malls that have been associated to that shop in the shops show page. This is my code:

Models:

```
class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mall_shops
    has_many :shops, :through => :mall_shops
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mall_shops
    has_many :malls, :through => :mall_shops
end

class MallShop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
    belongs_to :mall
end
```

Join table:-

```
create_table "malls_shops", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "shop_id"
  t.integer "mall_id"
end
```

Shop form:-

```
<%= form_for(@shop) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Which malls does it belong to?" %><br>
    <% Mall.all.each do |mall| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "shop[mall_ids][]", mall.id, @shop.malls.include?(mall) %>
      <%= mall.name %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as calling for the association from a given relation. For example:

**shops_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @shop.malls.each do |m| %>
  <%= m.name %><br>
<% end %>
```

Calling the `malls` method will return all of the associated malls to that given shop.